# Cypress code coverage: Only found unit test coverage

Tags: angular, testing, cypress

I'm trying to implement Cypress code coverage into my project. I'm using babel-plugin-istanbul as in their setup guide at https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage.

I set it up but I don't get any report at the end of the tests. All i get after each test is: "Only found unit test code coverage". At the end of all tests it says "Generating report [cypress/code-coverage] yet no report is ever created.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem. It seems that if I run my default babel configuration, unit tests work, but cypress says that the application as not been instrumented.

If I create a .babelrc that is cypress friendly, I see the same issue as you, but unit tests fail in the CI/CD pipeline because of "duplicate plugins".

Not sure if any of that helps, but maybe something from that troubleshooting might give you a lead.

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to this [issue](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage/issues/265).  End to End tests work, but not Unit Tests.  I'm using webpack on a Vue 3 application and get the same error.